# What is the best way to keep an asp:button from displaying it's URL on the status bar?

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to keep an asp:button from displaying it's URL on the status bar of the browser?  The button is currently defines like this:

```
<asp:button id="btnFind" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Find Info" 
            onclick="btnFind_Click">
</asp:button>
```

**Update:**

This appears to be specific to IE7,  IE6 and FF do not show the URL in the status bar.

Comment: This is with the asp:button control, not the LinkButton.

Comment: I can confirm the IE8 Beta also displays the Form action. I think this was added as a security thing.. Who knows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use FF so never noticed this, but the link does in fact appear in the status bar in IE..

I dont think you can overwrite it :( I initially thought maybe setting the ToolTip (al la "title") property might do it.. Seems it does not..

Looking at the source, what appears is nowhere to be found, so I would say this is a *browser* issue, I don't think you can do anything in code.. :(

### Update

Yeah, Looks like IE always posts whatever the form action is.. Can't see a way to override it, as yet..

Perhaps try explicitly setting it via JS?

### Update II

Done some more Googleing. Don't think there really is a "nice" way of doing it.. Unless you remove the form all together and post data some other way..

**Is it really worth that much? Generally this just tends to be the page name?**

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a link, I see this:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('btn','');
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, was looking at a LinkButton, not an ASP:Button. The ASP:Button shows the forms ACTION element like stated.

But, if you are trying to hide the DoPostBackCall,  the only way to do that is to directly manipulate window.status with javascript. **The downside is most browsers don't allow this anymore.**

To do that, in your page_load add:

```
btnFind.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","window.status = '';");
btnFind.Attributes.Add("onmouseout","window.status = '';");
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried in FF and got nothing, IE returned the parent FORM elements ACTION attribute.. I tried manually overriding the onmouse events to no avail.. Have you tested this?